# F#: appending the value of an option to list option

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#, lifting

I have a basic `append` function

```
let append item list = item  :: list
```

And i have a' list option and option `Some("something")`

```
let listOption = Some []
```

I want to add the value `"something"` to `listOption`. How can I do it without using pattern matching and `Option.get` but by lifting `append` function?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use *maybe* computation expression

```
type MaybeBuilder() =
    member this.Bind(m, f) = Option.bind f m
    member this.Return(x) = Some x

let maybe = new MaybeBuilder()
let append item list = item  :: list
let appendLifted item list =
    maybe {
        let! l = list
        let! i = item
        return append i l
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    appendLifted (Some "abc") (Some [])
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a home work...

If you want to add a value (not an option) at the head of a list option, you can simply do this which will return None if the list option is None:

```
let liftedAppend item optList =
    optList |> Option.bind (fun list -> Some (item :: list))
```

liftedAppend signature is:

```
'a -> 'a list option -> 'a list option
```

But talking about lifting stricto sensu, as the signature of your append function is:

```
'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

the signature of the lifted function should be:

```
'a option -> 'a list option -> 'a list option
```

That means the first argument have to be an option and I guess you want to check if it's Some or None. If so attentively read other's replies.

You can use something like this, which the de-sugared Lanayx's computation expression.

```
let liftedAppend optItem optList =
    optList |> Option.bind (fun list -> 
        optItem |> Option.bind (fun item -> Some (item :: list)))
```

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
listOption 
|> Option.map (append 11)
|> printfn "%A"  // Some [11]
```

but to create a lifted `append`:

```
let liftedAppend v = Option.map (append v)

listOption 
|> liftedAppend 11
|> printfn "%A" // Some [11]
```

The signature of the functions are:

- `val append      : 'a -> 'a list         > 'a list`
- `val liftedAppend: 'a -> 'a list option -> 'a list option`

To pass both parameters as options you can use `Option.map2`:

```
let liftedAppend2 vO = vO |> Option.map2 append

listOption 
|> liftedAppend2 (Some 11)
|> printfn "%A"  // Some [11]
```

Which has signature:

- `val liftedAppend2: a option -> 'a list option -> 'a list option`